# why this code has error

Tags: javascript, html

```
//this is a part of html code
<form>
    <b>user:</b> <input type="text" name="user" size="25"/>
    <input type="button" name ="submit" value="confirm" onclick= "mehdi(this.form)"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mehdi(rno){
        rno.user.value =  2 * Math.PI ;//this is error line user is unknown 

        alert(rno);
        return rno;
    }
</script>
```

what can i do?

Comment: `rno.user` is an HTMLInputElement and not its `value` property.

Comment: I copy/pasted that code and it ran without errors.

Comment: NExt time you edit you should leave the original question and highlight the changes. This only confuses people. Once you edited it according to one of the answers you question doesn't even make sense. Shame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
<form>
    <b>user:</b> <input type="text" name="user" size="25"/>
 <input type="button" name ="submit" value="confirm" onclick= "mehdi(this.form)">
</form>

 <script type="text/javascript">
          function mehdi(rno)
          {
           rno.user.value =  2 * Math.PI ;//this is error line user is unknown 

           alert(rno.user.value);
           return rno.user.value;
           }

 </script>
```